# How to remove specific line from multi-line string

Tags: java, string

I have below java string as command output

```
String output = "NIC     Value\n"
                + "------  -----\n"
                + "vmn0  on   \n"
                + "vmn1  on   \n"
                + "vmn2  on   \n"
                + "vmn3  on   \n"
                + "vmn4  on";
```

I want to remove second line with dash from above string. How can I do it?

I tried it using contains method but it is generating blank line after removing second line.

```
 if(output!=null && output.contains("-"))
            output = output.replace("-","");
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: `String newOutput = output.replace("------  -----\n", "");`.

Comment: yes I did same. But output  string still contains 7 lines. As it creates 2nd blank line

Comment: For the code you are showing, it will contain the second line still, because you don't remove the new line, or the spaces between the `-`s. But anyway, don't remove one character at a time from a string, that is horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to remove that line and use the result,

```
String result = output.replace("------  -----\n", "");
```

It will replace that line with an empty `String`

Comment: Yes. But can I remove empty string also. I need to delete empty line too

Comment: There won't be any empty line. Did you put `\n` also like I have put in here?

Answer (score 2):

This is complete answer you are looking for:

```
String output = "NIC     Value\n"
            + "------  -----\n"
            + "vmn0  on   \n"
            + "vmn1  on   \n"
            + "vmn2  on   \n"
            + "vmn3  on   \n"
            + "vmn4  on";

    String str = Stream.of(output.split("\n"))
                       .filter(s -> !s.contains("--"))
                       .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```